# JQuery autocompleter for dynamic input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have a webpage with jquery generating dynamic html input boxes.

Something like this appears on the page.

```
<input type="text" id="numbers[]" ></input>
<input type="text" id="numbers[]" ></input>
<input type="text" id="numbers[]" ></input>
<input type="text" id="numbers[]" ></input>
```

These text-boxes all use the same autocompleter, is it possible in jQuery to point my autocompleter at all of these?

Comment: Which autocompleter are you using?

And you should ensure each input has a different and valid id.

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

Comment: @Karl: You're quoting the wrong part of the spec. The name attribute is not the same thing as a name token. The name attribute can contain character data, which includes square brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all id should be unique in the whole document so your code is not correct.

What you probably mean is

```
<input type="text" name="numbers[]" ></input>
<input type="text" name="numbers[]" ></input>
<input type="text" name="numbers[]" ></input>
<input type="text" name="numbers[]" ></input>
```

To enable autocomplete on those boxes just use the selector that will match them all

```
var data = "foo bar baz";
$('input[name^=numbers]').autocomplete(data);
```

Comment: Sorry id is indeed incorrect. That worked perfectly, many thanks.

Comment: This is why you should validate your documents before asking for help.

Comment: i have a input box it allows user to type their country, Since i have list of country in text file, So when user starts typing `AM` `jQuery` should load all words from text file that matches `AM` in first two letter

Answer (score 0):

You could add a div that wraps input and that is never changed, then upon creation of new input store its id in jquery internal cache, just like this:

```
var $input = '<input name=somename[] type="text"/>';    
$('#mywrap').append($input);
$input.data('id', 'some id');
```

Then on you can access autocompleter in the following way:

```
$('#mywrap input').live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // and now do anything with the new id you have!
});
```